# Unable to filter out a specific object with a specific value from an array of objects. React ( todo app )

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-state

```
export default function Todos() {
  const [todoState, updateStateTodo] = useState([
    { id: 1, title: "I am a todo object", completed: false },
    { id: 2, title: "I am a todo object 2", completed: false },
    { id: 3, title: "I am a todo object 3", completed: false },
    { id: 4, title: "I am a todo object 4", completed: true },
    { id: 5, title: "I am a todo object 5", completed: false },
  ]);

  function handleChange(e) {
    const newArray = todoState.filter((todo) => todo.id === e.target.value);
    console.log(newArray);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  const todoItemArray = todoState.map((todo) => {
    return (
      <TodoItem title={todo.title} key={todo.id} completed={todo.completed} handleChange={handleChange} id={todo.id} />
    );
  });

  return <div>{todoItemArray}</div>;
}
```

I have 2 main components joined. A todo item, which renders a specific item. And a todos component which renders them all in a list. Im using function based components. My state is stored with a hook in my todos component and my todo items are getting their info from props which are defined in todos from the state. Each "todo" in the state has a ID, title, completed. Im trying to figure out a way to make handleChange() work and make a new array for now with just the selected  checkbox and that todos id. I dont know how to compare todo.id to the ID of the actual todo you clicked. e.target.value shows up as a number in the console of the one you clicked but when i filter() it doesnt work. (todo.id in filter() is working , i tested )

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass in a separate handler callback to each `TodoItem`

```
 const handleChange = (todo) => (e) => {
   let newArray = todoState.filter(element => element.id === todo.id)
   console.log(newArray)
 }

 const todoItemArray = todoState.map((todo) => {
   return (
    <TodoItem title={todo.title} key={todo.id} completed={todo.completed} handleChange={handleChange(todo)} id={todo.id} />
   );
 });
```

Comment: that makes sense, where do i specify the ( todo )? If this helps rn the newArray is just a placeholder, to make sure it works before i make it update the state